# Wordpress: Add Interger to User_nicename if it Exists in Database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a Wordpress site where users register on the front-end and add information about themselves. On registration I am forcing the `user_nicename` to be name-surname. I am then automatically creating 2 custom post types that act as profile pages for the new users. I am using the `user_nicename` as the title of both.

The problem is obviously if two people register with the same name.

So I would like to check the database before the `user_nicename` is updated to check if it already exists. If it does I would like to add an integer (in sequence) to the end of the `user_nicename`.

For instance:

- John-Smith
- John-Smith-2
- John-Smith-3
- Etc.

The code I have tried is as follows, but I'm not having any luck. The custom post types generate fine, but the `user_nicename` is not being appended with an integer.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
 add_action( 'user_registration_after_register_user_action', 'ur_insert_username', 1, 3 );
    function ur_insert_username( $valid_form_data, $form_id, $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $firstname = isset( $valid_form_data['first_name'] ) ? $valid_form_data['first_name']->value : '';
    $lastname = isset( $valid_form_data['last_name'] ) ? $valid_form_data['last_name']->value : '';
        
    {
    $custom_nicename = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $firstname . '-' . $lastname);
    {
    $i = 1;
    do { 
    $user = get_user_by('login', $custom_nicename);
    if( ! empty( $user ) ) {
        $i++;
        $custom_nicename =  $custom_nicename ."-" . $i;
    }
    }
    while ( ! empty( $user ) );
    }
    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->users,
        ['user_nicename' => $custom_nicename],
        ['ID' => $user_id]
        );
    }
    {
    $user_post_athlete = array(
            'post_title'   => $custom_nicename,
            'post_status'  => 'publish', // <- here is to publish
            'post_type'    => 'athlete', // <- change to your cpt
            'post_author'  => $user_id
        );
        
        $user_post_rivalry = array(
            'post_title'   => $custom_nicename,
            'post_status'  => 'publish', // <- here is to publish
            'post_type'    => 'rivalry', // <- change to your cpt
            'post_author'  => $user_id
        );
        
        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_post_athlete );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_post_rivalry );
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$user = get_user_by('login', $custom_nicename);` - you are not changing the value of `$custom_nicename` anywhere inside your while loop.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! I'm not sure I understand fully what you mean? I did just pick up that the issue lies with the 'get_user_by' function, as if i remove the loop, it still doesn't even update the 'nicename' even once. Could you perhaps expand if you don't mind?

Comment: `$custom_nicename =  $custom_nicename ."-" . $i;` - so after the first time this executes, `$custom_nicename` will now be something like `firstname-lastname-2`. (Not even starting correctly, at `1`.) Now what happens when you append `"-" . $i` to that again, in the next loop iteration ...? You'll get something like `firstname-lastname-2-3`

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I thought that it would loop in the 'do {} while' function for as long as the '@custom_nicename' is found to already exist in the database - updating the integer, rather than appending another?

Comment: _"updating the integer, rather than appending another"_ - no, of course not, you are doing string concatenation here. `foo` getting `-1` appended results in `foo-1`, and then `foo-1` getting `-2` appended, results in `foo-1-2`.

Comment: Ok thanks. What solution would you suggest?

Comment: Use two separate variables (like you originally had, don't know why you changed the code in the first place) - one to hold the "base" name (`firstname-lastname`), and use a second one to append your counter suffix to that base name.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to manage post type for user profile using post_author.

I guess you are adding post by code using wp_insert_post , so add "post_author" field to store user id in it. Wordpress will automatically manage slug of two different posts with same title. And you can associate posts and user using "post_author" field.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Editing my answer
get_user_by('login' will not work reason being login is 'username' and you need to search 'nickname'. You need to get user details by below code

```
$user_data=get_users(array(  
    'meta_key' => 'nickname', 
    'meta_value' => 'jaytesh'
));
echo "user id is".$user_data[0]->ID;
```

And Your code will change to (approx code)

```
add_action( 'user_registration_after_register_user_action', 'ur_insert_username', 1, 3 );
function ur_insert_username( $valid_form_data, $form_id, $user_id ) {
global $wpdb;

$firstname = isset( $valid_form_data['first_name'] ) ? $valid_form_data['first_name']->value : '';
$lastname = isset( $valid_form_data['last_name'] ) ? $valid_form_data['last_name']->value : '';
    
{
$custom_nicename = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $firstname . '-' . $lastname);
{
$i = 1;
do { 
$user_data=get_users(array(  
    'meta_key' => 'nickname', 
    'meta_value' => $custom_nicename
));
if( ! empty( $user_data[0]->ID ) ) {
    $i++;
    $custom_nicename =  $custom_nicename ."-" . $i;
}
}
while ( ! empty( $user_data[0]->ID ) );
}
$wpdb->update(
    $wpdb->users,
    ['user_nicename' => $custom_nicename],
    ['ID' => $user_id]
    );
}
{
$user_post_athlete = array(
        'post_title'   => $custom_nicename,
        'post_status'  => 'publish', // <- here is to publish
        'post_type'    => 'athlete', // <- change to your cpt
        'post_author'  => $user_id
    );
    
    $user_post_rivalry = array(
        'post_title'   => $custom_nicename,
        'post_status'  => 'publish', // <- here is to publish
        'post_type'    => 'rivalry', // <- change to your cpt
        'post_author'  => $user_id
    );
    
    // Insert the post into the database
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_post_athlete );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_post_rivalry );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaytesh! I need to keep the nicename and the custom post type titles the same for other reasons across the site, so while I agree that's how it should have been coded initially, it's not a viable solution right now unless I change a bunch of code elsewhere.

Comment: @Andrew get_user_by('login' will not work. You need to get user details by below code
`$user_data=get_users(array(  
    'meta_key' => 'nickname', 
    'meta_value' => 'jaytesh'
));
echo "user id is".$user_data[0]->ID;`

Comment: @Andrew I have edited your code in my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks Jaytesh! Unfortunately no luck. I've tried with 'nickname' 'nicename' and 'user_nicename', and none of them pick up duplicates in the database.